# Can I get the domain of a request with silex

Tags: php, silex

I want to create one silex application that listens to requests to routes to two domains. Depending on the domain the response should be different. 
I know I can simply inject a Request object and use that to get the host from, but I'd like to use a nicer way like [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html), but using Silex.

Is this possible and if so: how?

Comment: Why the downvote? Am I missing something super obvious?

Comment: well FWIW, I just upvoted you again. I had exactly the same question. Your question seems well-formed to me, and is relevant to the intent of StackOverflow, surely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bad question - I ended up here looking for a quick answer myself.

It turns out to be rather easy - you just need your instance of the Symfony Request which provides access to the following method:

```
$base_url = $request->getHost();
$app['monolog']->notice('Base path result', ['base_url' => $base_url])
```

My result:

[2016-02-19 10:04:15] api.INFO: Base path result [] {"base_url":"api-test.xonadu.com"}

I hope that's useful :)

Answer (score 3):

It should be as easy as calling the [`host()`](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.3/src/Silex/Route.php#L126) method for each route (you [can also do that on an entire ControllerCollection instance](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/ControllerCollection.php#L165) for all its routes) like so:

```
<?php

// initialization, etc.

$app->get('/', function() {
  return new Response("Only from my.host.com!");
})
->host('my.host.com')
;
```

Comment: Yes, this would work if the list of hosts is fixed, but the number of hosts will grow overtime. I'd rather not have to add a new route for each new host

Comment: Then probably the best way is to implement your own Route instance (or route Collection), you should rephrase your question to specify more in order tot get help (or you can have your hosts stored somewhere and load your routes dynamically using [controller as a services](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/service_controller.html))